# microsoft dynamics crm duplicate error

Tags: insert, duplicates, key, dynamics-crm

Scenario:

I wanted to import one solution to another solution 3 entities. I got this error.

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.DependencyBase' with unique index 'ndx_UniqueDependencyNodes'. The duplicate key value is (ad63qwed2-e83s4-417f-9e43-ce450were6e1, 96edxcvx06-91b0-49ea-bxcvcd-77c5qweqa8a665). The statement has been terminated.

Then I carried one by one. I did not get an error. But In the import environment, Ribbon Workbench Error when Publish.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtOSh.png)

If I look at sql;
I used to run code

```
select CustomControlDefaultConfigId, count(*) cnt
from CustomControlDefaultConfig
group by CustomControlDefaultConfigId
having count(*) > 1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDkf4.png)

What should I do?

Comment: What's the CRM version ? what rollup ? is it online ?

Comment: Hello Alex , version 8.1.0.359 , rollup admin, yes online ..

Comment: Then I'm afraid your only option is a support ticket to Microsoft